# Detect touchpad as touchpad

Tags: mouse, trackpad, alps

My touchpad seems to be recognized as a mouse instead of a touchpad. I have a Dell Precision M4600, and I am running Ubuntu 11.04 64-bit.

```
vegard@vegard-laptop:~$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ImPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint                    id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Laptop_Integrated_Webcam_FHD              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Even though it seems to detected properly, I do not have any *Touchpad* settings available in *Mouse Preferences*.

My problem, specifically, is that my clumsy hands touch the touchpad while I am typing, send errant clicks my way, and I'd like to disable the touchpad while typing.

Comment: I suppose GNOME's disable while typing option doesn't work then?

Comment: @htorque It is simply not present in *Mouse Preferences*. If it was there, I'd use it.

Answer (score 3):

Download psmouse-alps-1.3: http://www.dahetral.com/public-download/alps-psmouse-dlkm-for-3-2-and-3-5/view Then (using sudo / root):

```
Extract the folder psmouse-alps-1.3 to /usr/source
cd to /usr/source
dkms add psmouse-alps-1.3
dkms autoinstall
rmmod psmouse && modprobe psmouse
```

Bam! Working multitouch! :-)

(See also https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/606238/)
 - Tested on Dell M4700, Xubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/760142) with those ALPS touchpads (`ImPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint` is the entry for your touchpad).

Comment: This is a good explanation for why it does not work. However, I am interested in a more permanent fix besides patching drivers and compiling it myself.

Comment: The more permanent fix would be to wait for a kernel update for 11.04. However, I can't say how likely that will happen as it depends on the complexity/regression potential of the actual patch/fix if it gets backported or not.